# Why can you borrow a mutable reference and still use both?

Tags: rust, lifetime, rust-cargo, borrow-checker, borrowing

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rect {
    width: u32,
    height: u32,
}

fn main() {
    let mut r = Rect { width: 30, height: 30 };
    let b = &mut r;
    let c: &Rect = b;
    println!("{:?},{:?}", b, c);
}
```

In code, `b` is mutably borrowed and `c` is immutably borrowed, so this shouldn't compile, but that compiles and runs without any error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> this shouldn't compile

Why? Yes, `b` mutably borrows `r`. But `c` immutably borrows `b`, so now `b` is, well, immutably borrowed and you can't mutate it.

If you attempt to assign to any fields of `b`, then the compiler will immediately throw an error.

```rust
let mut r = Rect { width: 30, height: 30 };
let b = &mut r;
let c: &Rect = b;

// This assignment will fail, as yes, `b` is a
// mutable reference but it is immutably borrowed.
b.width = 40;

println!("{:?},{:?}", b, c);
```

The example is the same as if you remove `b` all together. You still wouldn't be able to mutate `r`, even though `r` is mutable.

```rust
let mut r = Rect { width: 30, height: 30 };
let c: &Rect = &r;

// This assignment will fail for the same reason,
// `r` is a mutable reference but it is immutably borrowed.
r.width = 40;

println!("{:?},{:?}", r, c);
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify and desugar your example:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a: i32 = 1;
    let b: &mut i32 = &mut a;
    let c: &i32 = &*b;
    println!("{:?},{:?}", b, c);
}
```

I think the source of confusion is that the `prinln!` macro looks like a regular function call but in reality isn't. If we replace the `println!` macro with a regular function:

```rust
fn func(format: &str, b: &mut i32, c: &i32) {}

fn main() {
    let mut a: i32 = 1;
    let b: &mut i32 = &mut a;
    let c: &i32 = &*b;
    func("{:?},{:?}", b, c);
}
```

Then we get the expected compiler error:

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `*b` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
 --> src/main.rs:7:5
  |
6 |     let c: &i32 = &*b;
  |                   --- immutable borrow occurs here
7 |     func("{:?},{:?}", b, c);
  |     ----^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |     |
  |     mutable borrow occurs here
  |     immutable borrow later used by call
```

So the question now becomes why does `println!` work where `func` fails. Let's take a closer look at `println!` by expanding it:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a: i32 = 1;
    let b: &mut i32 = &mut a;
    let c: &i32 = &*b;
    {
        ::std::io::_print(::core::fmt::Arguments::new_v1(
            &["", ",", "\n"],
            &match (&b, &c) { // borrows b & c again here
                (arg0, arg1) => [
                    ::core::fmt::ArgumentV1::new(arg0, ::core::fmt::Debug::fmt),
                    ::core::fmt::ArgumentV1::new(arg1, ::core::fmt::Debug::fmt),
                ],
            },
        ));
    };
}
```

The `println!` prepends `&` to its arguments, so if we revise `func` to do the same:

```rust
fn func(format: &str, b: &&mut i32, c: &&i32) {}

fn main() {
    let mut a: i32 = 1;
    let b: &mut i32 = &mut a;
    let c: &i32 = &*b;
    func("{:?},{:?}", &b, &c);
}
```

It now compiles.

So what have we learned here? If we mutably borrow some data, then immutably borrow from the mutable borrow, and then immutably borrow the mutable borrow and the immutable re-borrow of the mutable borrow, then there's no violation of Rust's ownership rules, since the immutable borrows are all borrowing from the same original mutable borrow which is not being mutated while the immutable borrows are alive.

Comment: "an immutable reference to a mutable reference" - No such thing in the code.

Comment: The "simplified example" confused me for a second, given that it isn't a simplified version of the code in the question. It would also be more confusing if `println!` didn't _take_ immutable references. So defining `func` as not taking 2 `&i32` is more confusing, and slightly makes it sound like the behavior is a macro vs function thing. :)

Comment: @SebastianRedl please elaborate.

Comment: @vallentin I've updated my answer to hopefully make it more clear.

Comment: The "If we replace the `println!` macro with a regular plain function" still suggests that `println!`/macros are special. When in actuality if it was `fn func(a: &i32, b: &i32)`, then the behavior would be the same. For instance `println!("{:?},{:?}", &mut a, &a);` would also still fail.

Comment: @vallentin I've updated my answer again. I don't think I'm suggesting macros are special, just the opposite: I'm demystifying the `println!` macro by expanding it and showing exactly what it is doing. I think this is valuable because when beginners see code like this `println!("{:?}", vec);` and the ownership of the `vec` variable is not actually moved anywhere they find it very magical and confusing. I think this is at least one of the underlying sources of OP's confusion which is why I decided to answer how I did.

Comment: I agree with your `vec` example, that can indeed be confusing to beginners. I didn't mean literally that you were suggesting it, poor wording on my part. I meant more that it was my interpretation reading it, so beginners might also misinterpreted that. :)